# Prevent Lazy Load of a Div in Laxy Load XT

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

Any idea how to **prevent lazy load xt from effecting certain divs**?

Here is a link to the github: https://github.com/ressio/lazy-load-xt

**I would like to prevent lazy load of class .mywrapperclass .myimagclass**, but cannot find any documentation showing how to achieve this.

**Thank you!**